# svnadmin load, how to keep the revision numbers

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn, svnadmin

I have dump a old repository from revision 12000 to 16000 and try to generate a new repository, everything is right expect the new one show wrong revision numbers(0 to 4000).

How do I preserve the revision number?

Here is what I have done:

```
svnadmin dump oldrepo -r 12000:16000> repodump
svndumpfilter include /xxx/xxx < repodump > repodump_new
svnadmin load repo_new < repodump_new
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because every new repository starts with revision number of 0.
Your svnadmin load is only a client that commit every single version in a new commit. If you want the same revision numbers in the destination repository, you must dump/load all revision numbers from source repository.